# git удаленные файлы не вошли в коммит

Tags: git, git-commit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

парни изучаю git пытался закомитить свой проект вроде вышло но после этого пишу git status и тут такое выскакивает, насколько я понял, в графе не могу закомитить, я потестил другие вещи написать вроде работают, но это там весит покоя не даёт пролейте свет на ситуацию и может я не то что-то нажимал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во время добавления файлов в репозиторий удаленные файлы были проигнорированы. Что бы в коммит вошли абсолютно все сделанные изменения можно использовать комманду `git add --all`, после чего закоммитить изменения `git commit -m "commit comment"`, и при необходимости запушить в remote репозиторий: `git push origin master`.

Так же командой `git commit -a -m "commit comment"`  можно объединить первое и второе действие.

Comment: спасибо помогло)))

Comment: @OlexiePolishchyk рад помочь) рекомендую настольный справочник по гиту: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git

Comment: @OlexiePolishchyk вижу линукс консоль и рекомендую использовать `tig`

Comment: *git commit -a -m "foo bar commit"* делает всё в одну команду

Comment: @0andriy спасибо, добавлю это в ответ